# Serviceworker cache-first & update resources in Background

Tags: web-applications, polymer, offline-caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm currently building a progressive web app with Polymer, which should mainly feel like a native app. I've already created a manifest, but even more important is, that the app loads as fast as possible. I thought of the following steps to do so:

Once Serviceworker is registered & all resources are cached, I want the Serviceworker to load the resources always from the cache, even with internet connection. During runtime, the web app should check if any new resources are available or any have changed. If so, download them in the background, save them in the cache, so that when the web app loads the next time, it uses the new resources.

Being relatively new to serviceworker and caching, any advice, link, or idea is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

*Updated based on Jeff Posnick's comment:*

Did you look into the [platinium-sw-cache](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/platinum-sw?active=platinum-sw-cache) element ? 
It is based on the [sw-toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox#built-in-handlers) and provides a couple caching strategies.

You would probably want the `fastest` caching strategy:

> Request the resource from both the cache and the network in parallel. Respond with whichever returns first. Usually this will be the cached version, if there is one. On the one hand this strategy will always make a network request, even if the resource is cached. On the other hand, if/when the network request completes the cache is updated, so that future cache reads will be more up-to-date.

```
<platinum-sw-register auto-register>
  <platinum-sw-cache defaultCacheStrategy="fastest"></platinum-sw-cache>
</platinum-sw-register>
```

Comment: `cacheFirst` will serve the responses quickly from the cache, but the previously cached entries won't ever get updated. For this use case, I'd recommend the `fastest` strategy, which will serve a response from the cache immediately, and then update the cached entry "in the background" so that it will be fresh the next time it's used. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox#toolboxfastest

Comment: you are of course right, thanks.
I will update the answer.